# Use of the IV for the CBC Block Cipher in TLS1.2

Tags: aes, block-cipher, tls, initialization-vector

I'm struggling to understand at what point a message is encrypted when looking at [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.2). The spec gives the generic block cipher in section 6.2.3.2 as:

```
struct {
    opaque IV[SecurityParameters.record_iv_length];
    block-ciphered struct {
        opaque content[TLSCompressed.length];
        opaque MAC[SecurityParameters.mac_length];
        uint8 padding[GenericBlockCipher.padding_length];
        uint8 padding_length;
    };
} GenericBlockCipher;
```

So my question is, does the IV get encrypted or not, and does the IV affect the padding?

Comment: The IV isn't encrypted because it's not in the block-ciphered struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the IV doesn't get encrypted. The IV is a random vector to make sure that the ciphertext is not identical for identical plaintext. This would leak information to any eavesdropper. It needs to be unique - and in the case of CBC, indistinguishable from random to the eavesdropper ("unpredictable") - but not confidential.

As the IV is separate from the ciphertext, it does not affect the padding. However, the RFC has this information:

> The padding length MUST be such that the total size of the
>         GenericBlockCipher structure is a multiple of the cipher's block
>         length.

The IV is included in this structure. This is still correct as the IV is specified as being exactly the same size as the block size (for CBC):

> the IV length is of length
>         `SecurityParameters.record_iv_length`, which is equal to the
>         `SecurityParameters.block_size`.